# A question about the names of the components of an interval

Tags: soft-question, definition

Suppose you have the interval $[n,10n]$. How do you call the $n$ in this interval? I think the $n$ can be called the "independent variable of the interval" (since the interval $[n,10n]$ can be written as $[n,f(n)]$, where $f(n)=10n$), but I'm not sure.

Any comments?

Comment: Personally I would simply call it a *parameter*

Comment: Is there a particular context you're working in?  In most contexts people don't really seem interested in how the interval "varies" as you change it's limits; all compact intervals have many identical topological and analytical properties anyway.

Comment: @grantfgates Suppose in the interval $[n,10n]$ you can replace $n$ with any positive integer. My question is: how do you call the $n$ in this interval?

Comment: @UserX Well, you could, but I'm asking about the problem you had this come up in.  Because it's not very often the exact boundaries of an interval matter in the applications I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: @grantfgates Example: "There is always a prime number in the interval $[n,10n]$, where $n$ can be any positive integer". I need to know another way of saying this. For example: "There is always a prime number in the interval $[n,10n]$, where the ... can be any positive integer". What can I replace "..." with? "Independent variable"? "Input"? Other words or expressions?

Comment: Pretty sure nothing here is standard.  I like parameter in that case though.